# Converting the file format to mp4 via the Sendto menu

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that converts ts and flv files in batches in the folder specified in the script, I need to convert only one or several files selected by me through the "Sendto" file menu. How to change this script so that you can convert video files from any folder of any disk without specifying these folders in the script and without batch processing, thanks.

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$path = "P:\repair"
$ffmpeg_exe = "P:\repair\ffmpeg.exe"

$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq ".ts" -or $_.Extension -eq ".flv"}
$file_num = 1
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $output_file = $(Join-Path $file.DirectoryName $file.BaseName) + ".mp4"
  $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "($file_num / $($files.Count)) Converting $($file.Name) to $($file.BaseName).mp4"
  Write-Host "Converting $($file.Name) to $($file.BaseName).mp4"
  if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $output_file)) {
    & $ffmpeg_exe -loglevel error -i $file.FullName -c copy $output_file
    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $output_file) {
      (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $output_file).CreationTime = $file.CreationTime
      (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $output_file).LastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime
      Write-Host "OK"
    } else {
      Write-Host "File $($file.BaseName).mp4 not found" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    }
  } else {
    Write-Host "File $($file.BaseName).mp4 already exists" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
  }
  if ($file_num -lt $files.Count) {
    $file_num++
  }
  Write-Host "`r"
}
$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "($file_num / $($files.Count)) Completed"
Write-Host "Completed"
Read-Host
```

created batch file:

```
@echo off
start PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%~dp0FLV+TS-to-mp4+data.ps1"
```

shortcut copied to folder - C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
but processing is still going on in bulk, all files in the folder. and I don't need it.